# Kotlin extension function on mutable property

Tags: properties, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm trying to set an extension function on a mutable property so I can reassign the property in the extension function. I wanted to know if it was possible.

My goals is to make `Date` extensions for easy access. For example:

```
fun Date.addDays(nrOfDays: Int): Date {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = this
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, nrOfDays)
    return cal.time
}
```

This function adds number of days to a date using a `Calendar` object. The problem is each time I have to return a new date which can be confusing to reassign each time you use this function.

What I've tried:

```
fun KMutableProperty0<Date>.addDays(nrOfDays: Int) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = this.get()
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, nrOfDays)
    this.set(cal.time)
}
```

Unfortunately this can't be used on a `Date` object.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Does this actually compile (either of your snippets)? `time` field on a `Calendar` object is of type `int`, but looks like you're assigning a `Date` value to it. And then again you're returning `cal.time` as `Date`, while it's an `int`.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński, both have no errors on my side, and `cal.time` is `java.util.Date`.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński Yes both compile, but the 2nd one can't be used on a `Date` object. `cal.time` returns a `Date`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I just couldn't read documentation straight and got confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot define an extension on a member property and call it fluently in Kotlin 1.0.3.

Your extension can be rewritten to work like this:

```
fun <T> KMutableProperty1<T, Date>.addDays(receiver: T, nrOfDays: Int) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = this.get(receiver)
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, nrOfDays)
    this.set(receiver, cal.time)
}
```

with the following usage:

```
class C(var date: Date) { ... }
val c = C(someDate())

C::date.addDays(c, 123)
```

With [bound callable references (likely supported in Kotlin 1.1)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6947) this will be possible with the following syntax:

```
c::date.addDays(123)
```

---

As @MarcinKoziński suggests, you can also mutate your `Date` objects without reassigning the property:

```
fun Date.addDays(nrOfDays: Int) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = this
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, nrOfDays)
    this.time = cal.timeInMillis
}
```

with usage:

```
class C(var date: Date)
val c = C(someDate())

c.date.addDays(123)
```

With this solution, you have to control the references to the `Date` object which is mutated. This solution works good with mutable objects, though it is not suitable for a property storing immutable ones.

Comment: The first option looks good enough to use, unfortunately I cannot get it to work. It has a receiver type mismatch. It also doesn't pop up in the auto completion. I'm using the date in a function, so I'm creating a var which is a date and try to call the extension function. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo, did you change the extension signature to `fun <T> KMutableProperty1<T, Date>.addDays(...)`? Works fine for me, the call is `C::date.addDays(c, 123)`.

Comment: Yeah I did change the signature. Did something else wrong, it's working now. 
It's not ideal, but it's something. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thank you for all the information! Hope that the bound callable references are released soon. I've accepted your answer because it answers my question. I also wanted to note the answer of @MarcinKoziński because that answer fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of returning a new `Date` and trying to update your property, you can just mutate the `Date` that your property already holds:

```
fun Date.addDays(nrOfDays: Int) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.time = this
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, nrOfDays)
    this.time = cal.timeInMillis
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I haven't done this.. That would fix my entire issue, thanks!

Comment: While this fixes my issue, the answer from @hotkey answers my question. So I'll have to accept his answer as the right one. But thank you so much for this answer, this fixes a lot of issues I had.